# Install project with custom windows forms

Tags: c#

is it possible to add custom window form to the installation process. I need it to display custom information, which I cannot do with the existing forms from the user interface. It can be shown in the Service.BeforeInstall event. What are the risks?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WiX - If I remember well, it allows you to embed custom forms. And with WiX you can actually change the order at which windows are displayed, and insert your custom info window where suitable.

[Wix Homepage](http://wix.sourceforge.net) on Source Forge